# FineUploader: how to process the response from uploadSuccess endpoint

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

After successful upload to s3, I'm using the uploadSuccess.endpoint url to kick off some brightcove api calls. I need to relay messages to the user depending on the results of these api calls, but I can't see how to add processing to the output from that endpoint url. callbacks.onComplete doesn't seem to see this output. Is there an event I can use to process that output? Here's the POST to uploadSuccess coming from FineUploader after successful s3 upload:

```
POST /cms/media/ajax/processS3Response.do HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 194
Origin: http://localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost:8080/cms/media/edit.do?id=71535
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

key=dev%2F2016%2F10%2Ftest-small-71535-orig.mp4&uuid=1b1b7e31-2966-4840-a17d-8ddb3d347a8c&name=test-small.mp4&bucket=my-bucket&etag=%22f515fa3e2b87d2959f605d6c1ef6043f%22&mediaid=71535
```

and here's the response i get from my server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 944
Date: Mon, 31 Oct 2016 21:43:48 GMT

{"bucket":"apollo-videouploads","etag":"\"f515fa3e2b87d2959f605d6c1ef6043f\"","bc_responses":{"cms_response":{"digital_master_id":null,"has_digital_master":false,"reference_id":"71535","link":null,"created_at":"2016-10-31T21:43:47.279Z","description":"jim test e","cue_points":[],"duration":null,"geo":null,"original_filename":null,"updated_at":"2016-10-31T21:43:47.295Z","delivery_type":"static_origin","text_tracks":[],"id":"5191685049001","state":"ACTIVE","published_at":"2016-10-31T21:43:47.279Z","ad_keys":null,"images":{},"custom_fields":{"ownerbrand":"Macworld","publishdate":"2016-10-31 00:00:00"},"long_description":"jim test e","sharing":null,"tags":[],"schedule":null,"economics":"AD_SUPPORTED","account_id":"2717258955001","name":"jim test e","complete":false,"folder_id":null},"di_response":{"id":"f3473660-f7df-4051-a5f1-81c3bf93f996"}},"uuid":"1b1b7e31-2966-4840-a17d-8ddb3d347a8c","key":"dev/2016/10/test-small-71535-orig.mp4"}
```

Comment: If you are not seeing the server response to the `uploadSuccess` request, then your server is likely either not returning the data you expect, or it is not returning valid JSON. Paste the _exact_ response from your server to this specific request, according to the browser, in your question.

Comment: i see the server response to uploadSuccess in the fineuploader debug logging, but what I would like to do is process that response browser-side and there are seems to be no way for me to assign an event handler for the response from uploadSuccess

Comment: The `onComplete` callback will contain this output. If you are not seeing this data in your `onComplete` callback, there is some issue with your response or your code.